# Restricting a function that is differentiable on R to a closed domain

Tags: real-analysis

Based on what I've learned in my real analysis class, functions are differentiable on open intervals in R. Take for example:

$f(x) = x^2$, $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $

If you restrict the domain as below to a closed interval, would our function be differentiable at x = 0 and x=4? Or would it still be differentiable only on the open interval (0,4)? My intuition tells me that in this specific case, our function is differentiable at 0 and 4. But if I consider the definition of the derivative, there is no $\delta$-ball around 0, one cannot take the limit at 0, and so the derivative does not exist at 0. Which line of thinking is correct?

$f(x) = x^2$, $f: [0,4] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two approaches when it comes to understanding what your choice, or any other differentiable choice, of $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfies at, say, 0 and at 4 when we consider $f\vert_{[0,4]}$:

1. We can say that $f:[0,4]\to\mathbb{R}$ is right-differentiable at $x=0$ and left-differentiable at $x=4$. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-differentiability)
2. We can say that $f\in C^1[0,4]$, meaning that $f:x\in(0,4)\mapsto x^2$ is such that both $f$ and $f'$ are uniformly continuous on $(0,4)$.

I hope this helps!